# Adding binaries to path with BOSH

Tags: cf-bosh

This seems like it should be done in the packaging phase of a job, but the documentation does it in the job's control script.

However when I ssh into the machine the binaries I added to the path are not in the path anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is correct, I'm not sure what docs you reference, but binaries should be define in `packages`

The `spec` file tells director where in `blobs` to find the binary:

```
---
name: bamboo-agent

dependencies:

files:
- bamboo/atlassian-bamboo-5.9.7.tar.gz
```

And the `packaging` file tells it where to place those files on the job's vm.

```
# abort script on any command that exits with a non zero value
set -e

# agent jar is within the full installation tar, pull it out.
tar -xzf $BOSH_COMPILE_TARGET/bamboo/atlassian-bamboo-5.9.7.tar.gz
cp -a atlassian-bamboo-5.9.7/atlassian-bamboo/admin/agent/atlassian-bamboo-agent-installer-5.9.7.jar $BOSH_INSTALL_TARGET/
```

Control scripts might use those binaries, but should not manipulate them.

See https://bosh.io/docs/create-release.html#pkg-skeletons for an overview of how packages fit into BOSH releases.